# Max size of string CMD that can be passed to Docker

Tags: docker, containers

In Docker references, I didn't find any information about how long the string can be passed to Docker CMD.

1. What are the limitations?
2. What is the maximum number of characters I can pass to CMD?

Comment: Depending on the os, you can try to run `getconf ARG_MAX` to see its limitation
For windows, there are written here 8191 characters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation).

They never mention from dockerfile limitation tho [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: If you're asking this question, write your extended startup sequence into a separate script and set the `CMD` to run the script.  It will be much easier to read, debug, and maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ZenithS You're right for Windows (8192 Characters), but Linux is not that easy.

To make it short: For Linux it's hardcoded to 64 or 128 kiB. You could check with `xargs --show-limits`, which gives a pretty detailed overview:

```
Your environment variables take up 5354 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2089750 <-- ARG_MAX
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2084396 <-- ARG_MAX - ENV
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072 <-- Hardcoded limit which applies actually (see below)
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

The hardcoded limit goes to `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` which is set to `PAGE_SIZE * 32`
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.16-rc7/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h#L15

With `getconf PAGE_SIZE` you can check (mostly 2048 or 4096 on modern platforms) so results to 64 or 128 kiB.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a simple test and found the limit of dockerfile line is 65535 on my CentOS 7/x64 machine.

```sh
#./build.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon    363kB
Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: dockerfile line greater than max allowed size of 65535
```